# Laravel Users table Update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

the image show is my `Users` table structure in Laravel 5.2, Yellow marks indicate that this rows are containing data when I sign up from Laravel Default Authentication. Now I want to update empty rows. I have created `profile.blade.php` for using `Post` method and `userController` is coded with:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use Image;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function getsignup()
    {
        return view('edit_profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }

    public function postsignup(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());         

        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            $img = $request->file('img');
            $file_name = time() . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($img)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/images/' . $file_name ));

        }
        $user = Auth::User();
        $user->img =$file_name;
        $user->city = 'city';
        $user->country = 'country';
        $user->company_name = 'comapany_name';
        $user->street_name = 'street_name';
        $user->apartment = 'apartment';
        $user->village = 'village';
        $user->city = 'city';
        $user->postal_code = 'postal_code';
        $user->post_office = 'post_office';
        $user->nid = 'nid';
        $user->phone = 'phone';

        $user->save();
        return back()->with('message', 'Successfully Registered!');
    }    
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BreGe.png)
But its only taking such value like 'city', 'company_name', etc. As i provided second image. I got stuck. I am new in Laravel. I hope you have a solution for me. Thanks In advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

why are the field updates inside the if condition?
this way it will only update if an image was uploaded

try this

```
public function postsignup(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());


        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            $img = $request->file('img');
            $file_name = time() . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($img)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/images/' . $file_name ));
            $user->img =$file_name;
            }


        $user = Auth::User();
        $user->city = $s;
        $user->country = 'country';
        $user->company_name = 'comapany_name';
        $user->street_name = 'street_name';
        $user->apartment = 'apartment';
        $user->village = 'village';
        $user->city = 'city';
        $user->img = isset($user->img)? $user->img : '';
        $user->postal_code = 'postal_code';
        $user->post_office = 'post_office';
        $user->nid = 'nid';
        $user->phone = '

        $user->save();
        return back()->with('message', 'Successfully Registered!');
    }
```

Comment: Hi! @Sherif. Thanks  for your replay. I ran your codes but it says that 'img' is null or empty. So i change little codes and give another screen shot of my table. Will you plz see that. Thanks Agai

Comment: `$file_name` is not gauranteed to be set, you need to allow the image to be null in the database if it is not required

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly works:

```
public function postsignup(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());


       if($request->hasFile('img')){
            $img = $request->file('img');
            $file_name = time() . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($img)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/images/' . $file_name ));

        }
        $user = Auth::User();
        $user->img =$file_name;
        $user->city = $request->city;
        $user->country = $request->country;
        $user->company_name = $request->comapany_name;
        $user->street_name = $request->street_name;
        $user->apartment = $request->apartment;
        $user->village = $request->village;
        $user->postal_code =$request ->postal_code;
        $user->post_office =$request->post_office;
        $user->nid = $request->nid;
        $user->phone = $request->phone;

        $user->save();
        return back()->with('message', 'Successfully Registered!');
    }
```